# problem with AsyncTask thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm reading some data from a DB in an AsyncTask thread....
in this way:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(DBAdapter... db) {

        try {

            db[0].openDataBase();

            Cursor c = db[0].getCursor3(db[0].TABLE_3, user_id);

            float[] viteza = new float[c.getCount()];

            String[] time = new String[c.getCount()];

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {

                    viteza[i] = Float.parseFloat(c.getString(3));
                    time[i] = c.getString(4);


                    publishProgress(????);

                    Thread.sleep(2500);

                    i++;
                } while (c.moveToNext());

            }
            c.close();
            db[0].close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Eroare", "doInBackground", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

My problem is that each time I get a new value for viteza[i] and time[i] I have to send them to

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(....?) {

}
```

both at the same time....but I don't know how to do that cause publishProgress() can take only one parameter!!!!

Can someone help me with this?Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work assuming you've got the data values in right order (getString(3) should be a number and getString(4) should be a time value).

```
protected Void doInBackground(DBAdapter... db) {
    // ... some db work
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        publishProgress(c.getString(3), c.getString(4));
        // ...
    }
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    float viteza = Float.parseFloat(values[0]);
    String time = values[1];
    // do something with the data that shows in UI
}
```

A full AsyncTask to test passing values is here:

```
private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String floatAsString = "3.14159265358979";
        String timeAsString = "06-01 07:32:02.579";
        publishProgress(floatAsString, timeAsString);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        float pi = Float.parseFloat(values[0]);
        Log.i("SimpleTask", String.format("Got values '%s' and '%s'. pi = %f", values[0], values[1], pi));
    }

}
```

which prints the output:

```
Got values '3.14159265358979' and '06-01 07:32:02.579'. pi = 3.141593
```

Comment: I did this way....viteza[contor]=Float.parseFloat(values[0]); and it throws an exception and I get force close:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
06-01 07:32:02.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFltImpl(Native Method)
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:321)

Comment: What are the exact values of your strings being passed to `onProgressUpdate()`? Check the length of the values array is 2 each time, and look at their values. The exception is telling you the value isn't parsable as a float.

Comment: Your error says it's trying to convert the value "06-01 07:32:02.579" which is your time string. It looks like you are parsing the wrong value as a float.

Comment: I've updated my code sample to include a full AsyncTask to show parsing of the string to a float.

Comment: U are nice.....but I figured where the problem was....Thank u...u have my accept!

Answer (score 0):

You could leave them both String and pass an array of String[] to publishProgress(), maintaining the same order, and then convert viteza[i]'s value to a float in publishProgress().  You could also put them into a super simple class and pass the object if you don't want to worry about the array order, but I would go with the array for something this small.

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    myTask.execute();
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] first = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        String[] second = {"5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};

        for(int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
                            //put together a string array with our values in the desired order
            String[] vals = {first[i], second[i]};
                            //publishProgress is what is used to call onProgressUpdate()
            publishProgress(vals);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String...strings ) {

                    //Strings are now in strings[0] and strings[1] in the order
                    //that they were put into vals array in doInBackground()
        String passedValues = strings[0] + "," + strings[1];

                    //Do whatever UI updates.
        TextView mytext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        mytext.setText(passedValues);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I have this protected void onProgressUpdate(String[]...array) {....}  where array[] has two elements....but array[0]=viteza[0]....How could I obtain back my elements....???

Comment: Added an example.  The code itself is lame, but it shows how to use onProgressUpdate and pass an array of values into it and access them.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a custom object that wraps the two values and pass this object as Progress as in:

```
private class MyAsynch extends AsyncTask<Void,MyObject,Void>{
```

JAL